# Listing buckets with AWS::S3 in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, sinatra

I'm trying to access my Amazon S3 account using the aws-s3 gem, but no matter what I do, I can't even print a bucket list.

Error:

```
undefined method `bytesize' for #<AWS::S3::Bucket:0x1b9e488>
```

From Code:

```
# hello_world.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'aws/s3'

get '/' do
  connection = AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
     :access_key_id     => '***',
     :secret_access_key => '***'
   )
  AWS::S3::Service.buckets
end
```

I'm not too experienced with Ruby, am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to output the whole set of buckets, but there is no string serialization method, that's why you're getting this error.

Try this one:

**app.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'aws/s3'

include AWS::S3

def s3_connect
  Base.establish_connection!(
    :access_key_id     => 'THISISMYACCESSKEYITMAYNOTBETHEBESTBUTITISMINE',
    :secret_access_key => 'HERPADERPSECRETKEYISSECRET'
  )
end

get '/' do
  s3_connect
  @buckets = Service.buckets
  erb :index
end

get '/bucket/:key' do
  s3_connect
  @bucket = Bucket.find(params[:key])
  erb :bucket
end
```

**View: index.erb**

```
<h1>Buckets</h1>
<ul>
  <% @buckets.each do |b| %>
    <li><a href='/bucket/<%= b.name %>'><%= b.name %></a> (<%= b.objects.length %> objects)</li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**View: bucket.erb**

```
<h1>Bucket: <%= @bucket.name %> Objects</h1>
<% @bucket.objects.each do |obj| %>
  Object: <%= obj.key %> <%= obj.about['content-length'] %> bytes<br/>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 9):

You really should obfuscate your AWS secred_access_key before pasting it at stackoverflow, or at least change it now before somebody starts playing with your buckets...